# How to see pull request like changes in intellij Idea

Tags: git, intellij-idea

We are using Bitbucket in our project and reviewing large pull requests in the browser is pain, I find it difficult to understand, what happened. I find it way easier to review the changes in directly in the Intellij Idea. If a feature branch is forked from develop (we are using git flow) and nobody has merged anything into the develop branch then I can use `Compare with local` feature after clicking on the commit I've made branch out of. However this doesn't work well, when someone merges anything into develop branch - the comparison tool obviously shows all the differences between branches, that means irrelevant changes for the feature I'm reviewing. Is there a way, how to compare two branches in Intellij Idea using some "pull request like" diff?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to see? If you only want to see your changes then compare to the commit you started your branch from... which is nice but means nothing because if you merge your branch, the code will contain your changes plus whatever is in develop anyway. Use VCS -> show git log and play with the options

Comment: I need to see the same changes I'd see in the pull request. That means how my changes from my branch will affect the target branch. The point is not to see all the changes my colleagues made and are not relevant to my branch.

Comment: But the changes you make are not isolated in their own fantasy world. Your changes, when merged, will be integrated with the changes your colleagues also made, so you'd want to see the end result, not just what you changed. In any case, if you control-v (vcs operations) and select branches, you then select Develop (for e.g.) and then from the menu opening on the right pick "Compare with Current" you can see all the commits (and diffs). Does that help you? (you can actually see it for both branches).

Comment: Agree with @MartinMarconcini
Also you can go to log, choose multiple commits while holding Ctrl/Cmd and choosing commits, then hit Cmd/Ctrl+D and you can navigate between files by pressing "Next/previous change" and by clicking on sandwich button (3 horizontal lines) - it will open file tree for you

Comment: I didn't express myself well. The changes in my commit don't live in their isolated realm, but the pull request shows only the "interactions" of my changes with the develop code, which I'm interested in. I don't want to see GUI changes, if I make an SQL migration script. Pull request displays only those relevant changes, branch diff shows all changes.

Comment: All a pull request does is nicely group a change-set. You start feature from commit A in develop. From then on, you commit X, and Y on feature. Develop perhaps has a B, C commits as well. When you merge back to develop, git is going to merge X, Y on top of develop's C commit. If you only want to see the DIFF between A in develop and Y in feature, select those particular commits. But that's not what develop will look like if you merge the PR. I think I know what you mean. To do this, however, I often push a Draft PR and look on the "web". (easier for ME).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for. Assuming there are no conflicts, I need to create local merge with `--no-ff` and `--no-commit` options like this:

```
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff --no-commit origin/my-feature-branch
```

And then I can see the changes I need as local changes in the Intellij Idea window. Finally I can abort my changes by `git merge --abort`